# jQuery DataTables Search Rendered Content

Tags: jquery, search, datatables

I have a datatable with one column that has a checkbox that is rendered on the serverside and displayed. I need to be able to have a column filter that shows rows where the input is checked, not checked, or neither. I toggle a class 'isChecked' my search is ignored and no results are returned when looking for it.

```
_table.column(index).search('isChecked', true, false, true).draw();
```

Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by reverting from 1.10.7 to 1.10.1 as 1.10.7 removes any markup from the data is searches. I believe this started in 1.10.4/5. With version 1.10.7, the entire contents of the cell, html/markup include, is in the string that the search is applied to. With the full contents I can use a regex to search for class/attributes on the input field to check if the checkbox is checked or not.